# The @property of Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is the following true:

weak = unsafe_unretain = assign

strong = retain

If it is why they are duplicated ? Which one should we choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not true. `weak` means that the object is not retained, and additionally, the variable/property will automatically be set to nil when the object is deallocated. `unsafe_unretained` means the object is not retained, but there is no automatic zeroing. `strong` and `retain` are equivalent.

Comment: if an object is deallocated, and the pointer to it is not zeroing (not set to nil), so what the pointer point to now?

Comment: It will point to the same location in memory as the object occupied, but attempts to access it (by sending a message to it) are likely to result in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. In other words, bad things will happen, which explains the advantage of using a `weak` property. Messages to `nil` are benign, and simply do nothing in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

`assign` is typically used for primitives, like `int` or `double`, since you're just assigning. `unsafe_unretained` is used for Objective-C objects that you *know* are not being retained, and understand why that's unsafe. `weak` is a new feature introduced in iOS 5 that is like `unsafe_unretained`, but has different semantics with ARC. Check out Apple's [Advanced Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf) guide for more info.

In practice, you'll almost never use `unsafe_unretained` if you're targeting iOS 5 or higher.

Comment: so , if ios4 is included, unsafe_unretained will be the choice?

Answer (score 2):

- `strong`: variable is retained during its scope. retain also works as a synonym for strong.
- `copy`: creates and retains a copy.
- `weak`: use it to point to an object without claiming ownership. Once the object is released, the pointer will be nil'ed.
- `unsafe_unretained`: same as weak but doesn't nil the pointer after release.
- `assign`: primitive values.

If you're targeting iOS 4, you cannot use weak. Use unsafe_unretained instead.
Before ARC, the default on properties was assign, now the default is strong.

Answer (score 1):

`weak` != `unsafe_unretain`

`weak` will automatically convert its pointer to a `nil` if the object it is pointing to is deallocated.

Going forward you should use `strong` & `weak` for objects and `assign` for primitive types

Comment: if an object is deallocated, and the pointer to it is not set to nil, so what the pointer point to now?

Comment: It will point to the deallocated memory. If you try to access it your app will crash.

Comment: if it is set to nil, nothing will happen?

Comment: It won't crash if you try to access it, sending messages to `nil` will just do nothing.